# Excel sum based on Automatic font color

Tags: vba, excel, colors

```
 Public Function ColorSum(ByVal target As range, ByVal MyColor As String)
    Dim Blacksum As Long, Othersum As Long, cel As range
    Application.Volatile

    Blacksum = 0
    Othersum = 0
    For Each cel In target
        If IsNumeric(cel.Value) Then
            If cel.Font.ColorIndex = 1 Then
                Blacksum = Blacksum + cel.Value
            Else
                Othersum = Othersum + cel.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cel

    ColorSum = IIf(LCase(MyColor) = "black", Blacksum, Othersum)

End Function
```

I am using the above code to calculate black colored sum totals and red colored sum totals in different rows of the excel sheet, but as you know there is a Automatic black color in Font options, when I am entering values with that Automatic color ( Black ) it doesn't sum under Black total, the Automatic Color (Black) cell value's total goes to Red color total instead of Black color total sum, I want the Automatic Black sum total should be included on Black sum total.

I am using 
`A11=colorsum(A1:A10,"black")`
`A11=colorsum(A1:A10,"red")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xlColorIndexNone (and xlNone) is a constant with a value of -4142.

xlColorIndexAutomatic (and xlAutomatic) is a constant with a value of -4105.

Using Excel's GUI to set a cell's colour to be "Automatic" will often set the ColorIndex to 1 but, if it was another colour before being set, it will set the ColorIndex to -4105 (i.e. xlColorIndexAutomatic).

So I would suggest you check for each of 1, xlColorIndexNone (or xlNone), and xlColorIndexAutomatic (or xlAutomatic).

In other words, change

```
If cel.Font.ColorIndex = 1 Then
```

to

```
If cel.Font.ColorIndex = 1 Or _
   cel.Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone Or _
   cel.Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic Then
```

Comment: kindly can you tell me what should be the code for this ?

Answer (score 1):

Long time ago I programmed vba but I think that the color index = 0 or xlNone or xlColorIndexAutomatic or xlColorIndexNone is the automatic and Black has colorIndex =1 and that is the reason. Could you try and play with the above mentioned suggested values?

Answer (score 1):

using `ColorIndex` as reference can be difficult because you'll have to memorize the index. i'd suggest use `color`

```
Function SumByFontColor(MyRange As Range, Optional MyColor As Range)
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Col As Long

    Application.Volatile

    If MyColor Is Nothing Then
        Col = Application.Caller.Font.Color
    Else
        Col = MyColor(1).Font.Color
    End If

    SumByFontColor = 0
    For Each Rng In MyRange
        If Rng.Font.Color = Col Then
            SumByFontColor = SumByFontColor + Rng.Value2
        End If
    Next Rng
End Function
```

there are two ways to use the formula, i hope the code is self explanatory:

[image]

> it must be noted that updating the color of a cell does not initiate the sheet to recalculate its formulas. So you must manually press `F9` to recalculate each time you update the cell's color.

Comment: how to get the red font cell values total in a particular cell ? it sums only black color value sum when I am using =sumbyfontcolor

Comment: @JyotirmayaChandra just color the font of the cell with the color you want to sum with.